# Open mutliple selenium webdrivers (tasks) with a command in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, bots

I am making a sneaker bot
It's Client based!
So I want to open multiple Web drivers in selenium
what I got:
`tasks = input("How many Drivers you want to open?")`  Then it should open the Number of drivers you have entered!
Like I enter 4:
Then it should open 4 drivers
also, these drivers should do something with the XPath search. I also want this amount of drivers to do the same thing but the most important thing is to open the amount of entered web drivers.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the number of tasks in integer form, I would recommend you to create an array, where you will put the `tasks` amount of browser references (for example, if you want 4 browsers, you will just put it in a forloop and append them to the array) and after that you will you can iterate through the array every time you will be performing any action (its like making it for 1 browser instance, just everything will be wrapped in a forloop that will iterate the array).